# Node-sass with multiple input files

Tags: sass, npm, node-sass

I'm using `node-sass` directly from the command line (a Makefile, really) to build my CSS.

The scss files are in different directories and they don't refer to each other. What I'd want to have is sassify these files to a single CSS output that I can read in from the HTML - with working source maps.

This is the current command I have in the Makefile:

```
$(OUT_MAIN_CSS): $(SCSS) Makefile $(node-sass)
    cat $(SCSS) > $(TMP_SCSS)
    $(node-sass) --output-style compressed --source-map $(OUT_MAIN_CSS).map $(TMP_SCSS) $@
    rm $(TMP_SCSS)
```

`OUT_MAIN_CSS` is `out/bundle.css`. `SCSS` is a list of the input files. `node-sass` is `node_modules/.bin/node-sass`.

I'd like to have a one-liner and not need a temporary file. Also, I'd like my source map references (for debugging) to lead to the original files, not the temporary file.

### node-sass syntax 1

```
node-sass [options] <input.scss> [output.css]
```

Here, `node-sass` insists on having just a single input file. If I have two or more, the second one gets treated as output, and its contents overridden.

There are some options for an "input directory" and "output directory" but I don't want to constrain my build processes by such rather arbitrary restrictions (yes, eventually I shall bend...).

### node-sass syntax 2

```
cat <input.scss> | node-sass [options] > output.css
```

This is more in line with the Unix mentality. Problem is twofold. My output file is in a subdirectory (`out/bundle.css`), which confuses source map references since `node-sass` has no idea of the output path.

There seems to be `--source-map-root` for that but I didn't get it to work...

I'm *clearly* placing a square bolt in a round hole here, am I not? How would you do this?

Is the best way to simply have one `ring.scss` in the root, to gather all the unrelated pieces together, and then sassify that?

Comment: The way I solved it: actually introducing dependencies between the scss files (they are components, some belonging to a larger one). This way, it's enough for the main (application) scss file to import just a few topmost ones. Source maps are correct, in this way. I'm aligned.

Answer (score 8):

Why not create a single `main` Sass file, import all of your files into it, and compile the `main` file with node-sass? This should result in a single file with correct sourcemaps.

Comment: Probably the way to go. I was experimenting with using Sass, trying to bridge traditional Unix build tools and JavaScript build tools together. It's interesting how different these two feel.

Comment: Yeah, Sass is originally a Ruby tool too, so you have all sorts of weird things going on :).

Comment: I can't do that because I need different css for different pages, but there are some files that I don't want to be compiled because they don't do anything by themselves

Comment: Update: it automatically knows to not compile files beginning with `_` so just specifying the root styles directory as input does what it needs to for me

Comment: Another use case could be a component library, and needing styles for each to be neatly compiled into a `css/components/my-button/module.css` type structure.

Answer (score 4):

For example, if you want to compile each `*.scss` file in folder `src/assets/scss` and output resulting `*.css` files into folder `dist` you can add script into your package.json file:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build:css": "node-sass -o dist src/assets/scss/",
...
```

and run compilation process from command line with:

```sh
npm run build:css
```

if you want to compile recursively, add `--recursive` flag in command:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build:css": "node-sass --recursive -o dist src/assets/scss/",
...
```

Answer (score 1):

This works perfectly

```
node-sass <input1.scss> [output1.css] && node-sass <input2.scss> [output2.css]
```

Answer (score 1):

```sh
node-sass <input1.scss> [output1.css] && node-sass <input2.scss> [output2.css]
```

```
 "scripts": {
"compile:sass": "node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.css && node-sass sass/mobile.scss css/mobile.css"
```

},

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

For performance reasons, I had to use a separate index.scss. So I used a folder instead of a single file, and it works. E.g.:

```
node-sass [options] styles/ [output.css]
```

Comment: It would not work, from the docs - `The input can be either a single .scss or .sass, or a directory. If the input is a directory the --output flag must also be supplied.`